# Timing of a simple code depends on whether it has already been run

Tags: c, io

The below simple C code simply reads in two files using C `open()` and `read()` functions.  It works fine, but I am interested in the timing.  And if I compile the code and run it, the first time I run, I get a time much longer (some times 3X) than I do if I run a second, third, fourth time etc.  There is something unique going on in that first execution.  This becomes obvious if the size of the input files gets to be about 10MB or larger.  Anyone know what is happening?  Is there anything to be done in the shell to make run times consistent?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*  for "open()": */
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/* for gettimeofday() ... */
#include <sys/time.h>

/* size of char buffer to hold input data.
   in a more involved code, this might be input
   or calculated.  This number should be at
   least as large as your input file size:
*/
#define BUFSIZE 536870912


int main() {

        int fd0, fd1, readstat0, readstat1;
        void *thebuffer0, *thebuffer1;
        struct timeval start_time, end_time;
        long int time_usec;

        fd0 = open("two_files_1of2.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd0 < 0) perror("open");
        fd1 = open("two_files_2of2.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd1 < 0) perror("open");

        thebuffer0 = calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));
        thebuffer1 = calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));

        gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);

        readstat0 = read(fd0, thebuffer0, BUFSIZE);
        if (readstat0 < 0) perror("reading 0");
        readstat1 = read(fd1, thebuffer1, BUFSIZE);
        if (readstat1 < 0) perror("reading 1");

        gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
        time_usec = 1000000*(end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) +
                    (end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec);
        printf("read %ld bytes from file 1 of 2 and %ld bytes from file 2 of 2 in %ld usec\n",
                  readstat0, readstat1, time_usec);

        close(fd0);
        close(fd1);
        free(thebuffer0);
        free(thebuffer1);

}
```

Comment: The OS is probably [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) the input file(s) in memory.

Comment: The data files are pretty large. Also my anti-virus will check out the executable, the first time.

Comment: The smarter the OS and other tools get, the harder it can be to make things like this consistent.  About all you can do is make N+1 runs in reasonably quick succession, and throw away the first.  Or if what you want to time is the actual reading, you may have to create brand-new input files (perhaps containing different or random data) for each run.  Or maybe run something off to the side, that reads a different big file, to deliberately poison the cache with that data, so that your program reading your file has to go to disk.

Comment: The disk drive itself may have a large internal cache.